# How to debug "Cannot POST /" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error:

> Cannot POST/.

Below is the code I'm trying to execute.

## Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var _ = require('underscore');
var db = require('./db.js');
var bcryptjs = require('bcryptjs');
var middleware = require('./middleware.js')(db);
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var todos = [];
var todoNextId = 1;
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.send('Todo API Root');
});

app.get('/todos', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
var query = req.query;
var where = {
    userId: req.user.get('id')
};

if (query.hasOwnProperty('completed') && query.completed === 'true') {
    where.completed = true;
} else if (query.hasOwnProperty('completed') && query.completed === 'false')      {
    where.completed = false;
}

if (query.hasOwnProperty('q') && query.q.length > 0) {
    where.description = {
        $like: '%' + query.q + '%'
    };
}

db.todo.findAll({
    where: where
}).then(function(todos) {
    res.json(todos);
}, function(e) {
    res.status(500).send();
});

});

app.get('/todos/:id', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
var todoId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

db.todo.findOne({
    where: {
        id: todoId, 
        userId: req.user.get('id')
    }
}).then(function(todo) {
    if (!!todo) {
        res.json(todo.toJSON());
    } else {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
}, function(e) {
    res.status(500).send();
});

});

app.post('/todos', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
var body = _.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');


db.todo.create(body).then(function(todo) {
    req.user.addTodo(todo).then(function () {
        return todo.reload();
    }).then(function (todo) {
        res.json(todo.toJSON());
    });
}, function(e) {
    res.status(400).json(e);
});

});

app.delete('/todos/:id', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
var todoId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

db.todo.destroy({
    where: {
        id: todoId,
        userId: req.user.get('id')
    }
}).then(function(rowsDeleted) {
    if (rowsDeleted === 0) {
        res.send(404).json({
            error: 'No todo with id'
        });
    } else {
        res.status(204).send();
    }
}, function() {
    res.status(500).send();
});
});

app.put('/todos/:id', middleware.requireAuthentication, function(req, res) {
var todoId = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
var body = _.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');
var attributes = {};

if (body.hasOwnProperty('completed')) {
    attributes.completed = body.completed;
}

if (body.hasOwnProperty('description')) {
    attributes.description = body.description;
}

db.todo.findOne({
    where: {
        id: todoId, 
        userId: req.user.get('id')
    }
}).then(function(todo) {
    if (todo) {
        todo.update(attributes).then(function(todo) {
            res.json(todo.toJSON());
        }, function(e) {
            res.status(400).json(e);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
}, function() {
    res.status(500).send();
});
});


app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');
db.user.create(body).then(function(user) {
res.json(user.toPublicJSON());
}, function(e) {
    res.status(400).json(e);
});

});

app.post('/users/login', function (req, res) {
var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');
var userInstance;

db.user.authenticate(body).then(function (user) {
    var token = user.generateToken('authentication');
    userInstance = user;

    return db.token.create({
        token: token
    });
}).then(function (tokenInstance) {
    res.header('Auth',
tokenInstance.get('token')).json(userInstance.toPublicJSON());
}).catch(function () {
    res.status(401).send();
});
});    

app.delete('/users/login', middleware.requireAuthentication, 
function (req, res) {
req.token.destroy().then(function () {
res.status(204).send();
}).catch(function () {
res.status(500).send();
});
});

db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(function() {
app.listen(PORT, function() {
    console.log('Express listening on port ' + PORT + '!');
});
});
```

This is my app.js file

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
var body = _.pick(req.body, 'email', 'password');


db.user.create(body).then(function(user) {
    res.json(user.toPublicJSON());
}, function(e) {
    res.status(400).json(e);
});

});
```

I've been trying this but not getting through.Not sure whether the html file I have is correct. Want to create an html file to post from, but mine is refusing to respond.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: I'm not getting errors in the console, I've using postman to do the same and it works all well. Just need a way for frontend routing.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `POST` to `/` because you haven't defined a route handler for `POST` requests to `/` (you only have one for `GET` to `/`).

Comment: not sure about what you're talking about. I'm using Postman to post, get, put and delete, but want to do it from the browser. Could you please provide me with your thoughts by giving me an example with code.

Comment: @Israel: we encourage people to take answers as starting points, rather than necessarily finished pieces of code that can be typed in verbatim. I imagine you could try `app.post('/', function(req, res) { });`, and of course you'll have to decide what goes in the controller function.